# Как открыть страницу пользователя в Facebook с помощью client_id?

Tags: facebook, facebook-api

Сделал авторизацию на сайте с помощью FB.

С помощью API получаю `client_id` пользователя, но столкнулся с проблемой, что `client_id`, который мне приходит, отличается от ID пользователя в FB если смотреть по адресной строке.

Как мне в таком случае найти этого пользователя в FB?

Answer (score 0):

Предполагается, что вам нужно запросить [разрешение `user_link`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/#reference-user_link) при входе, получение которого в свою очередь требует [одобрения администрации FB](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/login). Затем в профиле пользователя будет свойство `link`, в котором будет соответствующая ссылка.

Но этой ссылкой могут воспользоваться только другие пользователи из числа друзей друзей пользователя ("person's extended network"), потому вам она бесполезна и правильный ответ на этот вопрос будет - **никак**.

[Такие ограничения появились в мае 2018 года](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2018/05/01/facebook-login-updates-further-protect-privacy/) из-за скандала с Cambridge Analytica.